# Problem with posting values from ASP.NET to mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm developing a web site with mysql backend and I have the following problem. The site has a Search page that takes parameters in TextBoxes. When I'm posting the form and building the criteria from the values mysql doesn't return anything when I use greek characters. When I'm using Mysql Query Browser the same query works fine. I've set globalization in web.config and have everything in utf-8 encoding. Please Help.

Comment: can you show your code snippet

Comment: I am no expert but when I ran into this problem with Korean. I dumped my SQL query out and the version in code wasn't encoded properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in PHP recently and had to run some SQL before each query along the lines of:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Or:

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Might be worth giving this a try? Hopefully it will help.